# Even if SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS is set, http://authorize-server.com/...authorize(302) comes with set-cookies and JSESSIONID

Tags: spring-security

The oauth2 process is running normally, but http://authorize-server.com/...authorize (302) Bring a set cookie. Expected behavior: No set cookie should be included in any situation.
If the jsessionid for this process is required, should I manually end the session at/API/oauth2/endpoint? Because I want to use jwt for authentication by setting up resourceservice, the remaining steps do not require a session.

```kotlin
 @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .formLogin { it.disable() }
            .logout { it.disable() }
            .httpBasic { it.disable() }
            .anonymous { it.disable() }
            .oauth2ResourceServer { it.jwt { } }
            .cors { }
            .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
            .requestCache { it.requestCache(NullRequestCache()) }
            .securityContext {
                it.securityContextRepository(NullSecurityContextRepository())
                it.requireExplicitSave(true)
            }
            .authorizeHttpRequests {
                it.requestMatchers("/api/oauth2/endpoint").permitAll()
                it.requestMatchers("/api/ping").permitAll()
                it.anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .oauth2Login {
                it.authorizationEndpoint {
                    it.authorizationRequestResolver(
                        oAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                            registrationRepository,
                            oAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizer
                        )
                    )
                }
                it.tokenEndpoint {
                    it.accessTokenResponseClient(
                        oAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient(
                            oAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter,
                            mapOAuth2AccessTokenResponseConverter
                        )
                    )
                }
                it.userInfoEndpoint {
                    it.userService(oAuth2UserService)
                }
                it.defaultSuccessUrl("/api/oauth2/endpoint", false)
                it.failureHandler { request, response, exception ->
                    exception.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        return http.build()
    }
```

```kotlin
 @Bean
    fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
        val configuration = CorsConfiguration()
        configuration.allowedOriginPatterns = mutableListOf("*")
        configuration.allowedMethods = mutableListOf("*")
        configuration.allowedHeaders = mutableListOf("*")
        configuration.allowCredentials = true
        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)
        return source
    }

    @Bean
    fun decoder(): JwtDecoder {
        val originalKey = "b0f29fc0d32efdbabff03d4aae352b4936e69b0c3c6b8a0b067ae2453f96b431".toByteArray()
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(originalKey, "HmacSHA256")
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKeySpec).build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun encoder(): JwtEncoder {
        val originalKey = "b0f29fc0d32efdbabff03d4aae352b4936e69b0c3c6b8a0b067ae2453f96b431".toByteArray()
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(originalKey, "HmacSHA256")
        return NimbusJwtEncoder(ImmutableSecret(secretKeySpec))
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationConverter(): JwtAuthenticationConverter {
        val grantedAuthoritiesConverter = JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter()
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("")

        val authenticationConverter = JwtAuthenticationConverter()
        authenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter)
        return authenticationConverter
    }

    //    @Bean
    fun oAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
        clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository,
        oAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizer: OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizer
    ): OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {
        val resolver = DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI)
        resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(oAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizer)
        return resolver
    }

    //    @Bean
    fun oAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient(
        oAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter: OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter,
        mapOAuth2AccessTokenResponseConverter: MapOAuth2AccessTokenResponseConverter
    ): OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> {
        val authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient = DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient()
        authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(oAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter)


        val tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter = OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter()
        tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter.supportedMediaTypes = listOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter.setAccessTokenResponseConverter(mapOAuth2AccessTokenResponseConverter)

        val restTemplate = RestTemplate(listOf(FormHttpMessageConverter(), tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter))
        authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate)
        return authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient
    }
```

http://authorize-server.com/...authorize (302) should not include set cookie.(What I'm puzzled about is that the state parameter in the oauth2 process can determine the source, why do we still use cookie+jsessionid??)

Comment: OAuth2 is a browser based authentication with a login form, so you get a HTTP session. That doesn't mean that you are using a session cookie with the resource server. The JWT is HTTP stored in the session of your OAuth2 client.

Comment: oauth2login means your server is a client to an issuer. Your server will authenticate against the issuer and then issue a cookie to the browser. It is dangerous to hand out JWTs to browsers, and oauth2login is as stated in the specification a private client. So that is why you are getting a cookie. It is all explained in the specification.